# What are some of the best special-purpose mailing lists / forums for programmers?

Tags: forums, user-forums

In addition to (and prior to) Stack Overflow, there are quite a few special-purpose mailing lists and forums out there for programmers.

In my case, there's the Tomcat mailing list (i.e. users@tomcat.apache.org), the mysql mailing list (i.e. mysql@lists.mysql.com) and the many forums at java.sun.com. Then there are those used for more hardware-specific tasks (like ones for the NSLU2, etc.).

THe benefit of these lists is that questions are specific to the platform (i.e. Tomcat, MySql, the NSLU2, etc.) and also tend to have a great collection of experts and developers.

What are some of the ones you subscribe to and/or use most frequently, aside from Stack Overflow?

-Richard

Answer (score 0):

I use [Daniweb.com](http://www.daniweb.com/), it has a pretty rich userbase.  Not as efficient at getting questions answered as here, but it is a good resource for both programming and general IT help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a series of lists here: http://www.codify.com/lists, that a lot of aussie .net (and related) programmers are on. Been on there for years; and it's quite fun :)